# Output redirection on Windows overwrites line endings

Tags: c++, line-endings, windows-console, output-redirect

Sample C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::ofstream output(argv[1]);
        output << "Line 1\nLine 2\n" << std::flush;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Line 1\nLine 2\n" << std::flush;
    }
}
```

Direct output (Windows 7):

```
TestProgram.exe direct.txt
```

yields

```
Line 1[LF]
Line 2[LF]
```

Redirected output:

```
Testprogram.exe >redir.txt
```

yields

```
Line 1[CR][LF]
Line 2[CR][LF]
```

1. Where are the line endings being overwritten? `cout`? Console? Somewhere in between? And why?
2. Is there anything I can do about it? I've tried setting the `binary` flag on `std::cout` but that didn't change anything.

ETA:
Using echo+redirection I can send a LF character to a file, using

```
echo line 1◙line 2 >echo.txt
```

(where the LF character is made with Alt-10 on the keypad). So it seems to be a C++ problem.

Comment: I would guess the terminal absorbed the LR and the CR. The CR probably returned the caret to the beginning of the line and the LF would have cause it to scroll down one.

Comment: How did you set the binary flag?

Comment: `std::cout.setf(std::ios::binary);` Can't set it at creation time on `cout`, unless there's some way to close and reopen it.

Comment: `std::ios_base::binary` is an `openmode` flag, not a format flag. You can't set `std::cout` for binary output.

Comment: Yep, that would be why it didn't work.

Comment: On Windows, line endings are converted to `\n\r`. I'm not sure how to prevent it though.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed :-) The other part of the question is, what's doing the converting? Is it internal to C++ when writing to cout or something about redirection?

Comment: @chessbot: It's converted inside the stream. `std::cout` always converts, `std::ofstream` converts or not depending on mode passed to constructor/`open`. But I always thought the default is to convert as well. At least in the C API (`fopen`) it is.

Comment: @JanHudec Yeah, that's what the echo test seems to support. Do you know if there's any way to change that behavior on `cout`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: `\r\n`.